# Android Service example code leaking file descriptors

Tags: android, memory-leaks, file-descriptor

I'm running currently on Android 4.4.4 on a Nexus 4, and have also seen this issue on a Nexus 7 on 4.4.4.

I have an application built around the Service subclass example code found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

I'm using HelloService. I've been having crashes caused by too many files open, and I've gradually stripped the code down to the point where I now only have the example code in a project ([attached](http://files.cousins-sears.com/2f0i0b1D3v0e)). It's still leaking 3 file descriptors each time the service starts and stops.

Each time it starts and stops, lsof adds 3 rows like this:

```
com.cousi 11633     u0_a82   69       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[193985]
com.cousi 11633     u0_a82   70       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[193985]
com.cousi 11633     u0_a82   71       ???                ???       ???        ??? anon_inode:[eventpoll]
```

My actual application creates and stops the service frequently enough that after a time, it hits the limit of 1024 and is killed.

I've been searching extensively and have found a few other people that may be referencing the same issue, but haven't found anything in terms of a solution.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quitting your Handler's `Looper` inside `onDestroy()`.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mServiceLooper.quit();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Actually it looks like a bug inside of a sample.